# Convergence of sequence of functions with supremum metric

Tags: uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Let $f_n(x)=\sin(nx), x \in [0, \pi]$. Does this sequence converge with the supremum metric $d(f,g)=\sup_{x \in [0, \pi]}|f(x)-g(x)|$? I think there is a result stating that convergence in supremum metric is equivalent to uniform convergence with standard metric, so by this we know that $\sin(nx)$ does not even converge pointwise in $[0, \pi]$, so it does not converge uniformly and therefore does not converge with the supremum norm, is that correct?

Comment: For me, the standard metric for uniform convergence is the supremum metric $d$. The argument that $f_n$ does not converge pointwise and therefore does not converge uniformly is correct

Comment: Note the addition of backslashes on the $\sin, \sup$.

Comment: How do we know it doesn't converge pointwise?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich choosing $x= \frac {\pi}{2}, limf_n(\frac {n\pi}{2})$ does not exist, as it alternates between $-1, 0, 1$, is this wrong? Or is it wrong that uniform convergence is equivalent to convergence with the supremum metric?

Comment: that's fine. In fact it diverges for _every_ $x$, which is not quite so obvious, but just that one $x$ is enough here